# Rails query conditions for hour of creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In an attempt to summarise traffic data base on a time span, one cannot search invoking a component of a datetime object as such:

```
 txat0 = Transaction.where(['shop_id = ? AND created_at.hour = ?', shop, 0]).count
```

One could go via the SQL route (i.e. postgresql)

```
select extract(shop_id, hour from created_at) from transactions
```

and filter from there.

But what is a succinct way of achieving this with ruby or rails (performance is not a concern for this query) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you could do a mix and run the SQL part inside an ActiveRecord query.

What about:

```rb
Transaction.where("DATE_PART('hour', created_at) = ?", 0)
```

PS: I've ignored the `shop_id` clause in the above example, but you can just add it afterwards.

Comment: valid answer.  Only minor drawback is the reliance on db-specific syntax.  For mysql it would be `.where("HOUR(created_at) = ?", 0)`